# What is the alternate of Goto in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

I am using goto in azure synapse to skip certain code and jump to the label, its not working as expected. what is the alternate for that.

Comment: Writing procedural code that does not rely on GOTO?

Comment: Any update on this please?

Answer (score 0):

As `GOTO` is not supported in Azure Synapse Analytics, dedicated SQL pools, you need to write procedure code that does not rely on `GOTO`.

This example is taken from the [help page for GOTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/goto-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and works perfectly fine on normal SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Counter int;  
SET @Counter = 1;  
WHILE @Counter < 10  
BEGIN   
    SELECT @Counter  
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1  
    IF @Counter = 4 GOTO Branch_One --Jumps to the first branch.  
    IF @Counter = 5 GOTO Branch_Two  --This will never execute.  
END  
Branch_One:  
    SELECT 'Jumping To Branch One.'  
    GOTO Branch_Three; --This will prevent Branch_Two from executing.  
Branch_Two:  
    SELECT 'Jumping To Branch Two.'  
Branch_Three:  
    SELECT 'Jumping To Branch Three.';
```

This is that same code refactored without `GOTO`, using `IF ELSE` control flow language and `BEGIN END` blocks to contain multiple statements and `BREAK` to exit the loop:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT;  

SET @Counter = 1;  
WHILE @Counter < 10  
BEGIN   
    SELECT @Counter  
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1  
    IF @Counter = 4
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Jumping To Branch One.'  
        
        SELECT 'Jumping To Branch Three.';
        BREAK
    END 
    IF @Counter = 5 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Jumping To Branch Two.'  
    END 
END
```

There would be multiple ways to do it, eg write some of the inner code as functions or stored procedures.  This is just a simple example.  I have to say, I have not written a `GOTO` statement in SQL code for years as it tends to lead to so-called spaghetti code and can be hard to debug.